# iOS, Swift3 ) How to set notification sound as radio streaming?

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I'm developing ***`an alarm application with the radio play as the sound.`***

What most developers use as the sound of local notification is `'UNNotificationSound.default()'`

But **that is the static sound** and what I want is ***the streaming sound of target radio downloaded from the network.***

Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that is possible. Furthermore, the length of the audio in local notifications is limited to 30 seconds.